# Pythonic JSON encode/decode of object containing dictionary instance variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Let's say I have a python class that has instance variables that are dictionaries.  I'm new-ish to JSON and looking for the most *pythonic* way to encode/decode lists of these objects to/from .json files.

I'm curious if there is a clever way to use an `object_hook` to decode things that contain dictionaries as the typical encoder works inside->out as I understand.  I guess I could encode the dictionary into an ugly list of 2-item lists (??) and then handle that with the decoder?

Here's what I've got now in a reproducible example.  It works, but I suspect that it could be improved.  Curious if there is a way to handle this with custom decoder or `object_hook` or other pythonic approach

```
import json
from typing import Dict

class Critic():
    def __init__(self, name: str, reviews: Dict[str, int]):
        self.name = name
        self.reviews = reviews

    @staticmethod
    def encode(obj):
        return {"name": obj.name, "reviews": obj.reviews}

    @staticmethod
    def decode(obj):
        # ??? Can it be done ???
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.reviews}'

x1 = Critic('Bob', {'Jaws':4, 'Star Wars':5})
x2 = Critic('Jim', {'Dune':3, 'Top Gun 2':4})

data = json.dumps([x1, x2], default=Critic.encode, indent=2)
#print(data)

# load it, then parse the result "manually"
retrieved = json.loads(data)
res = []
for item in retrieved:
    res.append(Critic(**item))

print(res)
```

Yields (as expected):

```
[Bob, {'Jaws': 4, 'Star Wars': 5}, Jim, {'Dune': 3, 'Top Gun 2': 4}]
```

Comment: This isnt an answer to your question, which I think is a good one that should be answered. But I just want to say, serializing user-defined types to JSON and back is not trivial. For simple cases you can do something ad-hoc, but you should really consider using a library that solves this problem already, eg. [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) (which provides runtime validation), or more old-school, [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Note that "expected" result is not valid JSON

Comment: @buran I didn't "expect" JSON, I expect a list of `Critic` objects, which is what I received...proper de-serialization

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hmmm.  Thanks.  I haven't delved into `pydantic` and didn't know that it was a good serialization tool.  I'll poke around w/ that.  These data sets are small and manually created, so I'm just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: You can  always write your custom encoders/decoders with decorators/registries for handling hierarchies. However, there is no correct way. If you are dealing with a relatively complex set of objects, opting in for a library like pydantic is a good idea. You will end up customzing some of the behavior. But, its has its perks like runtime data validation (OOB), and is pretty performant. There are few downsides, one of which I feel like pydantic I think was built with web-developers in mind.

Comment: Hm, you want JSON, but didn't expect JSON... What kind of JSON you expect? Even if what you show is not the JSON you expect, in  what you show `Bob` and `Jim` should be in single quotes

Comment: @UmeshTimalsina Thanks.  Yeah, as I mentioned, the data is small and hand-curated, so I feel like `pydantic` may be a sledgehammer for a thumbtack in this case.  But I'm always up to learn a new pkg.  I'm curious about your comment about a custom encoder/decoder...that, I think, is what I'm asking about if there is a clever approach, I'm all ears!

Comment: @buran  Ahhhh...maybe I'm not clear.  The 2 objects were encoded into json as the `data` object.  Then I de-serialized that `json` data object (which is not shown) back into two `Critic` objects, which are shown in the list `res` as their `__repr__` values.  The "Yield" is the `__repr__` of the 2 objects.  :)